# Formatting a disk using PowerShell without prompting for confirmation

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-3.0

I have added data disks to Azure virtual machines and I need to create a volume for them.

I have used the following code to create the volume:

```
$disk = Get-Disk | where-object PartitionStyle -eq "RAW"  
$disk | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT  
$partition = $disk | New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter F  
$partition | Format-Volume -Confirm:$false -Force
```

While creating the volume, it asks for confirmation before formatting the disk.

I want to avoid this confirmation box. I tried `-Confirm:$false -Force` but it still prompts for confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed my problem. Confirmation popup does not appears while using the following code.

```
$disk = Get-Disk | where-object PartitionStyle -eq "RAW"  
Initialize-Disk -Number $disk.Number -PartitionStyle MBR -confirm:$false  
New-Partition -DiskNumber $disk.Number -UseMaximumSize -IsActive | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "Local Disk" -confirm:$False  
Set-Partition -DiskNumber $disk.Number -PartitionNumber 1 -NewDriveLetter F
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears this may be a bug with how `Format-Volume` handles -Confirm as discussed here: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11088429-format-volume-force-parameter-does-not-work

The workaround suggested is to set `$confirmpreference = 'none'` before you start.

You might also want to grab the current $confirmpreference in to a variable first and then put it back to what it was afterwards. E.g:

```
$disk = Get-Disk | where-object PartitionStyle -eq "RAW"  
$disk | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle GPT  
$partition = $disk | New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter F  

$currentconfirm = $confirmpreference
$confirmpreference = 'none'
$partition | Format-Volume -Force  
$confirmpreference = $currentconfirm
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Mark. It does not fix my problem. Popup still occurs and ask user confirmation for formatting data disks.

Comment: Try it without -force maybe? (Not sure why that would make a difference but you never know). What is your powershell version?

Comment: Powershell version is 4 @Mark.

Comment: @sp I think you need to specify -IsActive on the New-Partition command.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stop-Service -Name ShellHWDetection
$Disk = Get-Disk 2
# $Disk | Clear-Disk -RemoveData -Confirm:$false
$Disk | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR
$Disk | New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter T | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "DiskLevel" -Confirm:$false -Force
Start-Service -Name ShellHWDetection
Above code worked for me Stop and Start of  ShellHWDetection is the key here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear-Disk $DiskNum -RemoveData -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$path="d:\vhd\newvhd.vhdx"
$newVHD=New-VHD -Path $path -Dynamic -SizeBytes 2TB | Mount-VHD -NoDriveLetter -Passthru |Initialize-Disk -Passthru |New-Partition -UseMaximumSize |Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -Confirm:$false -Force
$driverletter = ls function:[d-z]: -n | ?{ !(test-path $_) } | select -First 1
$newVHD|Get-Partition | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter ($driverletter.replace(':',''))
```

Comment: Upvote for the
$driverletter = ls function:[d-z]: -n | ?{ !(test-path $_) } | select -First 1

This is required for a equal solution without popup